# Excel- Return multiple value in one cell from multiple rows

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup

I try to VLOOKUP but it can only returns 1 value. I want my result to return multiple email and my lookup value is the multiple names in one cell. The first cell is the value I want to match with my lookup table.
[image: result.]

Below is my lookup table where everybody email is here, but how I achieve the result like aa@g.vom;bb@g.com, so I can just automate a reminder email in VBA using lookup emails earlier? How I can achieve this?

[image]

I also got this error when I debug, I cannot get the selected emails
[image]

```
Sub getEmails()
Dim toNames As Range
Set toNames = Range("J3:J500") ' names input by user

Dim names As Range
Set names = Range("Email!B3:C25") ' names range from lookup table from different worksheet

Dim splitNames
splitNames = Split(toNames, ",")

Dim selectedEmails As String

For i = 0 To UBound(splitNames)
    findRange = names.Find(What:=splitNames(i), LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

    ' if match found, get the email and store to selected emails variable
    If Not findRange Is Nothing Then
    selectedEmails = selectedEmails & Range("B" & findRange.Row) & ";"
    End If


Next i

'output emails
Range("Q3:Q500") = selectedEmails
End Sub
```

Comment: That was exactly I don't want to do. I cannot predict what name the staff gonna write in the future. So I need to have a formula to lookup the value

Comment: I would recommend you just do multiple VLookups within a loop in VBA.  So, if `Pui Kuan, Eric` is the input field, `Split` it into individual names, do VLookups on each of the individual names, and concatenate the results.

Comment: Can you show me the example based on VBA that I have scripted above? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So you want to enter a set of names in a cell and get the corresponding emails from the table in another cell. Try the below code. I have assumed that the names were entered separated by commas and the resulting emails are separated by ";"

```
Sub getEmails()
        Dim toNames As Range
        Set toNames = Range("D25") ' names input by user

        Dim names As Range
        Set names = Range("A25:A39") ' names range from lookup table

        Dim splitNames
        splitNames = Split(toNames, ",")

        Dim selectedEmails As String
        Dim findRange As Range

        For i = 0 To UBound(splitNames)
            ' find the range matching the name
            findRange = names.Find(What:=splitNames(i), LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

           ' if match found, get the email and store to selected emails variable
            If Not findRange Is Nothing Then
                selectedEmails = selectedEmails & Range("B" & findRange.Row) & ";"
            End If

        Next i

        'output emails
        Range("D26") = selectedEmails
    End Sub
```

Also this will show run time error if any of the names isn't found in the list.

Comment: I have already write this in vba. but my lookup table is from another sheet? and I have compiled error

Comment: @gpsrosak, Fine! Update your post with your own code and state where it's failing and why.

Comment: @user3598756 agreed. OP - You should show your solution. we can try to help. Changing the lookup table to another sheet is not a big issue. Google this.

Comment: however, this solution does what you intended to do. you might have to make changes to make it more robust :)

Comment: Try `Set names = Sheet("Email").Range("B3:C25")`

Comment: And I thought you want all emails in a single cell. So why are you doing `Range("Q3:Q500") = selectedEmails`. Try `Range("Q3") = selectedEmails`

Comment: I get Sub or Function not defined and syntax error at set names

Comment: Should be sheets. `Set names = Sheets("Email").Range("B3:C25")`

Comment: Error '13, type mismatch

Comment: Can you debug and tell which line gives that error. http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/debugging.html  . Also, are all the names you have input, present in the list with emails?

Comment: Revised my code. removed `After:=ActiveCell,` as it requires you to select the first cell in the data to search. Now not required.

Comment: Why I cannot run, always type mismatch and when I debug it highlighted at sub getEmails() and state that sub not define

Comment: I got error here selectedEmails = selectedEmails & Range("B" & ActiveCell.Row) & ";" Error 1004, application defined & defined error

Comment: I have already paste my debug result above. Please help @nightcrawler23

Comment: you have changed the code than what i posted. `Dim findRange ...` , `findRange = names.Find(...` are missing